# Inequality in 3 variables (conjecture)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, conjectures

Let $a, b, c$ be nonnegative real numbers such that $a+b+c=3$.
If $0<k\leq 3+2\sqrt{3}$, then $$\frac{a}{b^2+k}+\frac{b}{c^2+k}+\frac{c}{a^2+k}\geq \frac{3}{1+k}$$
If $k=3+2\sqrt{3}$, then equality occurs if $a=b=c=1$ or $a=0$, $b=1-\sqrt{3}$ and $c=\sqrt{3}$ or any cyclic permutation thereof. This inequality can be found in Vasile Cirtoaje's **Discrete inequalities, Volume 4** - page 61. Any idea for this inequality? Thank you!

Comment: in this book is no proof?

Comment: if this inequality is **conjectured** by vasile cirtoaje I doubt if someone could prove it in a short time.vasile cirtoaje is a master in inequalities and it would be very hard to tackle an inequality he did not proved.

Comment: It is enough to prove only $k=3+2\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

This has been solved. A proof was published in the "Gazeta matematica", a Romanian mathematics magazine for high school students:

Martin Bottesch. On a conjecture of Vasile Cirtoaje. Gazeta Matematica, Seria B, 12/2015.

http://ssmr.ro/gazeta/gmb/2015/12/articol.pdf